# Is there any way to run Apps Script web app with triggers

Tags: web-services, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a *Apps Script web App which performs all the work by its own only it's need to be opened manually*.Now I just want to use **triggers** to open that web app at a particular time.

Here is the link of my code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQTU37F2FMIP

*In this link only the recording part is there.After this the video file gets uploaded to my Dropbox which is not included as I lost that code **but if this code could execute with triggers then I will work on it and Provide the code here.***

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "all the work". Please add more details.

Comment: Ok I am Adding more Details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably set up a trigger to execute a script the performs the get with UrlFetchApp.fetch();

Comment: Will it execute the java script on the page?

Comment: I lack understand of your intentions and probably require an example.  So far you have said little and  offered no [mcve].

Comment: I actually want to (record a canvas 'code is provided') and then upload that video to my Cloud Storage using Java Script this works fine if I manually open the web app.Now I want apps script to do this work at a particular time means open the web app and execute the java script on the web app.

Comment: Perhaps you can execute that javascript on a Window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

Will canvas element execute on window.onload(I have provided the code)